# Compare two lists of Scala to check oneOf/Contains

Tags: scala

lets say I have 2 lists:

```
listOfCountries =       List("United States", "Belgium", "Germany")
SecondlistOfCountries = List("Italy", "France", "Germany")
```

oneOf:

I want to check if there is at least one item that appears in both lists (the example will be "true")

Contains:

I want to check if one of the items in the SecondlistOfCountries list contains one of the items in the listOfCountries list (as a substring)

how would you do something like this in a clean Scala way?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

oneOf:

```
listOfCountries.exists(SecondlistOfCountries.contains)
```

[ Thanks to @Ava for this version, which is much better than my original solution ]

contains:

```
SecondlistOfCountries.exists(c => listOfCountries.exists(c.contains))
```

Answer (score 5):

oneOf can be also written as:

```
listOfCountries.exists(SecondlistOfCountries.contains)
```

For contains I suggest the same as @Tim.

Comment: I would just point out that it would be better to convert the `secondlistOfCountries` to a `Set` before doing this check for efficiency. Also, you may just convert both to sets and do an intersect but I think this would be faster.